# When binding event to multiple elements at once, new instance for each element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have **100** BUTTONS in my page ( each of them has **class**='**btn**').

Also I have a **single**  **button** which **prepare** all the **other**  100 buttons.

```
<input type='button' onclick='bindTheClickevent()' />
```

When pressed, - it calls `bindTheClickevent()` - (which binds the click event to all 100 others).

In the Script Section I put:

```
function bindTheClickevent ()
{
        $(".btn").bind('click',function () {
          $(this).css('color','red');
         });
}
```

### Questions

**1**) In **memory**, how many *instances* of the *anonymous function* are *created*?

**2**) In memory, Does the `bindTheClickevent()` function  will ever *be free (GC)*? - please notice that the Bind is called **inside** the `bindTheClickevent` function...

**3**) **When**, eventually - the `bindTheClickevent` function *will be free to GC* ?

### Lets make a change

```
function bindTheClickevent ()
    {
            $(".btn").bind('click',function () {
              changeColor($(this));
             });
    }

function changeColor(obj)
{
 $(obj).css('color','red');
}
```

### Now - after the change

**1**) Is there any difference if I Do that?

**2**) In **memory**, how many *instances* of the *anonymous function* are *created*?

**3**) Does the `bindTheClickevent()` function  will ever *be free (GC)* ? - please notice that the Bind is called **inside** the `bindTheClickevent` function...

Comment: ??? What is it that you're doing?  It doesn't make much sense to have a DOM 0 event handler which just binds *another* event handler ...  is this just some kind of browser behavior research topic?

Comment: @Pointy ,Hi. I just gave a simple situation ( not in real life) and i want to learn the behavior.

Comment: In your second example, you call `changeColor($(this));`, that is, you're passing a jQuery object. Inside `changeColor`, you're wrapping it in a jQuery object again: `$(obj)`. This is unnecessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"1) In memory , how many instances of the anonymous function are created ?"*

Which anonymous function?

For the inline `onclick`, you get a function assigned to the `onclick` property of the element like this:

```
function(event) {

    bindTheClickevent();

}
```

... or similar depending on the implementation. That function will be free for GC when the element is dereferenced or the function is dereferenced from the `onclick` property.

With respect to the jQuery code:

```
$(".btn").bind('click',function () {
    $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

...while the anonymous function is shared, what you don't see is that if the elements in question do not already have a jQuery handler bound, jQuery will *internally* create a unique function for each element.

That internal handler is what *actually* gets bound to the element, and when the element receives an event, that handler is invoked, analyzes the event, and invokes the handler you originally passed (if necessary).

This means ***100 jQuery bound elements equals 101 unique function instances***.

In order to make sure that any handlers bound using jQuery are GC'd, you need to make sure that you ***always use jQuery to remove DOM elements***. If you don't, all the data (including handlers) stored in `jQuery.cache` doesn't get cleaned up, and so they'll always be referenced via the global `jQuery` namespace.

---

**EDIT:**

Given that there are `100` elements that have the class `btn`, that don't have any handlers bound by jQuery, then this code:

```
$(".btn").bind('click',function () {
    $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

...will create `101` unique `Function` instances.

Why `101`?

Well, what jQuery does is the first time you bind a handler to an element, it internally creates a *unique* generic handler for every element. This is the handler that is actually invoked when an event occurs, and handles all event types.

*Your handler function is **never** actually bound to the element.*

So that generic internal handler when invoked will analyze the event that took place, and see if any handlers have been associated with the given element using `.bind()` that match that event type. If so, it calls the handler that passed.

Now let's say you bind another handler:

```
$(".btn").bind('mouseenter',function () {
    $(this).css('color','blue');
});
```

...since we're binding to the *same* elements, they already have the necessary *internal handler* and another does not need to be created. So all that happens is that the function you pass is referenced internally, and is invoked by the generic internal handler when needed.

As such, given the code snippets above, there now exists `102` unique `Function` instances.

Comment: why the extra anonymous function ? I Explictly told him to go to the declared function " bindTheClickevent "

Comment: How can the anonymous function be shared?  If "bindTheClickEvent" were to return that anonymous function, would not each invocation return a separate instance?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If you're talking about the inline `onclick`, that's just how it works. Your string `"bindTheClickevent();"` gets `eval`'d, and wrapped in an anonymous function.

Comment: @Pointy: I think there's some confusion in this question as to what is being bound where. I'm assuming there's only one inline `onclick`, and the `.btn` selection is entirely separate. That's the one that is shared. (I'm also assuming the inline one is only invoked once.)

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ , you right. theres only 1 button ( outsider) which 'activate' the other 100 by calling one time the bindTheClickevent()

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - so what do you say about jondavidjohn's answer ? he says only 1

Comment: @RoyiNamir: As far as the jQuery handler, with respect to *your* anonymous function, there's only one. With respect to what happens internally, every element gets a unique handler, which invokes your handler. So your handler + 1 internal handler per element equals *n elements + 1*. If you bind additional handlers to the same element(s) via jQuery, they will use the same internal handler that has already been bound.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ , handler is not a function its a pointer to it. so there are 100 internal distinct  handler but to HOW MANY FUNCTIONS ? 100 ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I'm talking about unique `Function` instances, not merely pointers to a common function. If you do `$('.btn').click(function(){});`, and there are 100 `.btn` elements that do not yet have any handlers bound, *your* function will be shared, but internally *jQuery* will create a separate and unique function instance for every element.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - sorry to bother you  but how can you say 'function is Shared' - meaning 1 function is shared , while jQuery creates 100 NEW functions.. I thought when i share function I share 1. and if i dont want to share so create 100. but here you say both of things...?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I updated my answer. *Your* function is shared. But for *every* element that gets a handler bound by jQuery, jQuery will *internally* create a *separate* function that *actually* gets bound to the element. *Your* function is *never* directly bound to the element. The *internal* handler is a generic handler that handles *all events* that occur on that element, and manually calls the function(s) you create.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - So : If I create one function - the MASTER function is shared by jquery to all .btnElements  Like CLONING ...so if the function size in memory is 1kb so actually it occupy 1*100 kb ...correct?

Comment: Every call to ".bind()" creates a new Function instance. The code may or may not be shared internally.  None of those functions will be `===` to any other function, [as shown in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ks5W/).

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ and i think you are meanning that the master function is 'broadcasted' seperatly to each of the elements. If you say that internally jquery creates a new function so why in http://jsfiddle.net/4aRCv/5/ i see the counter increasing without dependency on what i pressed ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Well, not really like cloning. I'm just saying that for every element there is a unique *internal* function that is actually bound to the element *instead* of yours. You never actually see that function. That internal function is the one that gets invoked. When an event occurs, that function looks up *your* function in a table, and invokes it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Forget that jsFiddle example. It is illustrating a different concept than what you're asking. Your question confused things a bit since you're binding the handlers via another handler. It isn't clear if the inline handler is invoked once or several times.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ , so in memory terms  occupied by the function there are 1kb*100 bytes in memory ? each for a new function ?

Comment: @Pointy: I'm assuming there's only one call to `.bind()` against a selection that returned `100` elements. In that case, the anonymous function passed to `bind()` is shared among all instances, but internally jQuery creates a unique handler for each unique element.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Assuming each function instance is 1kb, then actually 101kb total for a single call to `.bind()` where `100` elements were found.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ , pointy has removed its answer. i think he  agrees with John. can you please read johns last conversation with pointy ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Much of the conversion has to do with the fact that we can interpret your code differently. I'm making the assumption that your inline handler is *only invoked once*, and therefore `.bind()` is only called once. Pointy was illustrating the fact that if your inline handler is invoked more than once, additional functions will be created. John was showing that if you create functions inside the invocation of another function, each function will be unique.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - pointy was wrong at the start since he didnt understood the question at the begining and he corrected himself. leave it for now. my inline element is invoked ONCE !. john DOESNT say that  each function will be unique. he says there are only 1 instance. So...?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: jondavidjohn is correct that there is only one instance of **your** function. But **internally**, jQuery creates *a separate function instance* for every element. You'd never know about it unless you study the source a bit, or dig through `jQuery.cache`.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ If  internally there is a function for each element , how come hes counter is increasing http://jsfiddle.net/4aRCv/5/ ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Like I said, forget that counter example. It introduces an entirely different concept of variable scope where all the functions created in a loop are referencing the same `counter` variable. It is using a cryptic technique called an *immediately invoked function expression*, and it isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ  this article made me ask the question... http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closuresleak/index3.shtml

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Ah, well that would have probably been helpful to know up front. `;o)` Yes, if you use jQuery's event binding system, it avoids some potential memory leaks *as long as you use jQuery to remove elements from the DOM*. As it is, the handler passed to `.bind()` does not reference any elements that existed in the variable scope, and you aren't adding any massive data to the element or function objects, so you should be safe from any leaks as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ , in the future can i ask you more internal js question via reference from this thread ? :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Well, StackOverflow discourages extended discussions, but you may want to hang out in the [chat area](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). I'm not there too often, but lots of others are who would discuss your questions. :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like **only one** instance of the function is created in both circumstances.  It appears as though **References** to the anonymous function are attached as the event handlers for each element.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4aRCv/3/)** - Using a closure to show the sharing of scope between button event handlers.

**Note** that this can cause interesting behavior if you involve closures because all elements will share the same function (and closure scope).

And no, your declared functions will not be GC'd because of their global scope.

***Additionally***

To attach them independently (not by reference), loop over the selected elements with `.each()` and attach the function individually.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4aRCv/4/)**

```
$('.btn').each(function() {
    $(this).bind('click',function() {
        // each '.btn' has it's own copy of
        // this anonymous function
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't believe that this is true. Each invocation of "bindTheClickEvent" will, of necessity, create a new instance of Function for the event handler.  (Now, internally, the JavaScript engine might be able to share the actual code among them, but there'll still be distinct instances of Function.)

Comment: @Pointy There is only **one** invocation of `bindTheClickEvent()`

Comment: @jondavidjohn yeah but there are 100 other anonymous functions which created inside it ( different ones ) ...?

Comment: That is what I'm telling you, look at my jsfiddle examples above, it appears as though all event handlers when attached as a group, share the function scope and each element gets a reference to the event handling function...

Comment: Not sure how else I would explain my above examples behaving as they do.

Comment: @jondavidjohn , by this example http://jsfiddle.net/4aRCv/5/ i see that the counter is increasing each time no matter to which i press... Can i conclude that they share the same instance of the method ?

Comment: This answer is just incorrect.  [Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/7ks5W/)  Every invocation of the `function` expression that comprises the parameter passed to the jQuery ".bind()" method creates a distinct Function instance.

Comment: @Pointy That has nothing to do with what we're talking about, you're just maintaining an array of created functions, Objects(and therefore Functions) do not ever successfully compare.

Comment: @RoyiNamir That is exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: I get it now, @johndavidjohn -- it makes perfect sense.  Sorry to put you through so much crap for my one measly upvote :-)

Comment: @Pointy It's cool man, Everyone is here to get to the bottom of things. It's what makes this site so educational, and if you thought you have something to add/correct I'm glad you pursued it.

Comment: @jondavidjohn , now im really confused... one shared function via one instance ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir That is what appears to be true.

Comment: @jondavidjohn , Ӫ_._Ӫ and me talked about it. can you have a look at it and tell me what you think ? thank you very much man.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: To add some clarity, jondavidjohn is illustrating what happens specifically with *your* function, and gave an additional example of creating identical (but unique) functions inside the repeated invocation of an `.each()` callback. I was describing what happens internally since jQuery creates unique handlers under the hood.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ if its unique functions so how come he saves the counter value ?  jsfiddle.net/4aRCv/5

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like these:

```
for (someiterations)
{
    $(myobj).bind("click",function()
    {
        // ...bla...
    });
}
```

In this case you are creating a new function each iteration.
In your function this is not happening because you are passing the function to a parameter, so **there is a place which has stored it's reference** (yea the function param) that will do something like this:

```
for (iterations)
{
    myob.addEventHandler(event, funcref);
}
```

So should be ok, now:

1. Don't think so, not sure of the syntax however.
2. 1 as I explained
3. No because it's in the global scope and it's not assigned to an instance, you can think of it as a constant, not as a variable

**Note:** The anonymous function will not be released, it's referenced by the event handler.